# Add asterisk in kable if cells satisfy condition based on another matrix

Tags: r, matrix, r-markdown, kable

I have a matrix `m` that will be passed to the `kable` package. I'd like to include an asterisk to every cell in `m[c(1,3,5,7,9,11,13), 1:7]` where the corresponding elements in `CI` are `FALSE`.

I want the output to look like this:

[image]

data:

```
CI <- structure(c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, NA, NA, NA, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, NA, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, NA, NA, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), .Dim = c(7L, 7L), .Dimnames = list(
    i = c("Aaa", "Aa", "A", "Baa", "Ba", "B", "Caa"), j = c("Aaa", 
    "Aa", "A", "Baa", "Ba", "B", "Caa")))

m <- structure(c("Aaa", "", "Aa", "", "A", "", "Baa", "", "Ba", "", 
"B", "", "Caa", "", "37.14%", "(5.78%)", "8.76%", "(1.71%)", 
"3.48%", "(1.03%)", "1.61%", "(0.92%)", "0.00%", "(0.00%)", "0.00%", 
"(0.00%)", "0.00%", "(0.00%)", "35.71%", "(5.73%)", "47.81%", 
"(3.02%)", "22.15%", "(2.34%)", "14.52%", "(2.58%)", "7.76%", 
"(2.48%)", "9.46%", "(3.40%)", "0.00%", "(0.00%)", "22.86%", 
"(5.02%)", "21.90%", "(2.50%)", "48.10%", "(2.81%)", "30.11%", 
"(3.36%)", "15.52%", "(3.36%)", "12.16%", "(3.80%)", "2.70%", 
"(2.67%)", "2.86%", "(1.99%)", "13.87%", "(2.09%)", "17.41%", 
"(2.13%)", "26.34%", "(3.23%)", "30.17%", "(4.26%)", "21.62%", 
"(4.79%)", "10.81%", "(5.10%)", "1.43%", "(1.42%)", "5.11%", 
"(1.33%)", "6.01%", "(1.34%)", "17.20%", "(2.77%)", "25.00%", 
"(4.02%)", "18.92%", "(4.55%)", "21.62%", "(6.77%)", "0.00%", 
"(0.00%)", "2.55%", "(0.95%)", "2.22%", "(0.83%)", "8.60%", "(2.06%)", 
"14.66%", "(3.28%)", "18.92%", "(4.55%)", "35.14%", "(7.85%)", 
"0.00%", "(0.00%)", "0.00%", "(0.00%)", "0.63%", "(0.45%)", "1.61%", 
"(0.92%)", "6.90%", "(2.35%)", "18.92%", "(4.55%)", "29.73%", 
"(7.51%)", "70", NA, "274", NA, "316", NA, "186", NA, "116", 
NA, "74", NA, "37", NA), .Dim = c(14L, 9L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("Prior", "Aaa", "Aa", "A", "Baa", "Ba", "B", "Caa", 
    "Obs.")))
```

Answer (score 4):

We could use `paste` after subsetting the elements based on the TRUE values in 'CI'

```
i1 <- !is.na(CI) & CI
m[, colnames(CI)][i1] <-  paste0(m[, colnames(CI)][i1], "*")
```